# how to make a counter button in angular/typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

what i am trying to do is click a button add 1 times 1 but that count is not lost when reloading the page

```
  idi(){
this.suma=this.suma+1;
}
```

I only have this, but when reloading the page the value is lost and it starts from 0

Comment: Because your app reloads and the value resets to 0. You'll need to use localStorage to preserve across reloads.

Answer (score 0):

please use `localStorage` to store the information and retrieve it back once the page reloads.

`localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');` stores the value

`const cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');` retrieves the value.

More info here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage